# Saving an XML file to a specific folder

Tags: c#

I am trying to write code that will save an XML file to a location, so I attempted using

```
Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"settings.xml");
```

which returns the directory "C:\Users\myName\Desktop\ProgramFolder\assembly\settings.xml" I am using this code to give me a general idea of where the user is executing my program since it is a portable program. Now knowing where the program is being executed I want to create my file in the directory "ProgramFolder\Settings" which already exists. I am just not sure how I can go about doing this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
            string propertyFile = @"C:\Users\myName\Desktop\ProgramFolder\assembly\settings.xml";
            string propertyFolder = propertyFile.Substring(0, propertyFile.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            string newXML = propertyFolder + "newXML.xml";

            //XmlDocument doc name of xml document in code
            doc.Save(newXML);​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
string baseDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            string newPath = baseDirectory.Substring(0, baseDirectory.LastIndexOf("ProgramFolder") + 14);
            newPath = newPath + "settings.xml";
            doc.Save(newPath);
```

Is that what you wanted to know?